# `run` method in allias analysis llvm

Tags: c++, llvm

I want to implement alias analysis for llvm. [Documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/AliasAnalysis.html#required-initialization-calls) says that the alias analysis implementation should implement function `run`:

```
bool run(Module &M) {
  InitializeAliasAnalysis(this);
  // Perform analysis here...
  return false;
}
```

However I cannot find function `run` in llvm source code, for exmaple file `lib/Analysis/BasicAliasAnalysis.cpp` does not have it, nor any cpp file in `lib/Analyisi`.
What is the `run` method for `basicaa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this information is outdated. The method you need to override depends on the kind of pass you derive from: `runOnModule` for a module pass, `runOnFunction` for a function pass, etc.

`BasicAliasAnalysis` itself does not use any `runOn...` method because it inherits from `ImmutablePass` - an immutable pass is a pass which is never actually ran, so there's no point in inheriting its `runOnModule` method.

Remember that the primary method you need to implement when you add your own alias analysis is `alias` - this is the method which gets queried. If your custom alias analysis does not need to first analyze the module - like `BaseAliasAnalysis` doesn't - then you can also inherit an `ImmutablePass` and ignore the `runOnModule` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why BasicAliasAnaylysis.cpp does not have any `runOn...` function?